# Conntrack gets incorrect forwarding rules for outgoing protocol 41

Tags: iptables, nat, 6to4, wrt54g

I'm trying to forward protocol 41 (ipv6-in-ipv4) for an HE tunnel through a WRT54G running Tomato 1.28. Tomato 1.28 is running a 2.4 kernel that knows absolutely nothing about protocol 41, except that it is named "ipv6". Having a 2.4 kernel also appears to mean that conntrack can't just be disabled: there are no "raw" iptables rules.

I can set up rules so that incoming packets are DNAT-ed to the correct internal host. If the remote host sends something over the tunnel first, everything works fine. Packets can flow over the tunnel in both directions with proper NATing, and I get a `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` entry like this:

`unknown  41 599 src=72.52.104.74 dst=67.180.229.14 src=10.1.0.3 dst=72.52.104.74 use=1 mark=0`

The entry says it's for the unknown protocol 41, has a timeout of 599 more seconds if no more traffic is received, and has one pair of source and destination addresses on the initiating side (which is the WAN side) and another on the receiving side (which is the LAN side).

But if my system tries to send a packet out over the tunnel first, the source address does not get translated to the address of the router like it should, and I get a conntrack entry like this:

`unknown  41 589 src=10.1.0.3 dst=72.52.104.74 [UNREPLIED] src=72.52.104.74 dst=10.1.0.3 use=1 mark=0`

As long as my machine keeps trying to use the tunnel, it keeps this bogus conntrack entry alive, and I can see the packets leaving my router for the cable modem with the internal source address still attached, causing them to be dropped and never get where they're going.

To get my tunnel to come up, I have to bring down the tunnel interface on my end, use the HE ping tool to induce some IPv6 traffic to come down the pipe, and, while the 10-minute timeout is still active on the correct conntrack entry, bring my end of the tunnel back up again--and then ensure it is never idle for 10 minutes at a stretch. I *can* do that, but it's pretty stupid.

Right now I have my forwarding rules set up like this:

```
# Send incoming ipv6-in-ipv4 packets to the correct host
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p 41 -s 72.52.104.74 -j DNAT --to 10.1.0.3

# Allow those packets through the firewall
iptables -I FORWARD -p 41 -d 10.1.0.3 -j ACCEPT

# Things I have added to try and solve my problem, which didn't work:

# Remove the default masquerade-everything rule
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 10
# Masquerade only protocols other than 41. Conntrack still gets its bogus entries, 
# and if I get the correct entry in it still works.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p ! 41 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also at one point tried setting up an SNAT rule like this:

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p 41 -s 10.1.0.3 -j SNAT --to 67.180.229.14`

But as far as I could tell, that was no help either.

So my question is:

1) Has anyone ever gotten protocol 41 to forward through a WRT54G running Tomato successfully? If so, what special firewall rules did you use?

2) Why does the router think it doesn't have to do source address translation on outgoing protocol 41?

Comment: The venerable WRT54G might still have some useful life left in it, depending on its specific hardware revision, but I would give up on Tomato. Everyone else has.

Comment: Can you recommend a firmware with better support for IPv6? Or even native tunnel support? I could run OpenWRT on the thing, but it's not powerful enough to run the OpenWRT web UI, so I'd be doing everything by hand.

Comment: I run OpenWRT Barrier Breaker on everything I have at home, which is currently _five_ routers of various models and ages, and have run its nightlies for quite a while. I wouldn't consider the lack of a web UI a significant disadvantage, at least after you get used to OpenWRT's configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p 41 -s 72.52.104.74 -j DNAT --to 10.1.0.3
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```